# How can I restrict access to a view only to two specific users each time in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I already know about the `[Authorize]` attribute, which let's one restrict access to certain views or actions or controllers. The point is that my situation is a bit different. I have an `ActionResult` which is defined like this:

```
public ActionResult Ticket(int tid)
{
    var ticket = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketID == tid).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(ticket);
}
```

And my `Ticket` model is defined like this:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    public string FirstPartyId { get; set; }

    public string SecondPartyId { get; set; }

    // some more irrelevant properties
}
```

So, the point is that when the `Ticket` view is opened with the specific `TicketID`, I want only the users whose ids are equal to `FirstPartyId` and `SecondPartyId` of that ticket to be able to see the view. Other users simply won't be able to view it. I really don't know how to achieve this. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you give me some code example?

Comment: Why can't you change your query to `Where(t => t.TicketID == tid && t.FirstPatyId == userId && t.SecondPartyId == userId)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check inside Action user's id and check if is equal to FirstPartyId or SecondPartyId

```
public ActionResult Ticket(int tid)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var ticket = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketID == tid).FirstOrDefault();
    // check if null
    if(ticket == null)
    {
         return HttpNotFound();
    }
    if(userId != ticket.FirstPartyId || userId != SecondPartyId)
    {
          return HttpNotFound(); // return 404 or redirect here
    }
    return View(ticket);
}
```

Comment: You should create a custom authorize attribute.